# confusion matrix of OOB score in RandomForestClassifier sklearn?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, random-forest

I build RandomForestClassifier in sklearn with OOB. I want to get a prediction of OOB and confusion matrix of OOB. This is very simple in R. But what I see? `oob_score_` ? I have 90% of `oob_score_`, but model failed in 75% - model predict one class every where! Where OOB prediction and OOB confusion matrix?

P.S  `sklearn.metrics` have 2 parameters. But confusion matrix of OOB it's attribute of a random forest! Its confusion matrix (true_class, OOB_prediction)
And OOB error rate is `1 - rf.oob_score_` or what ?